# Porque o evento Activated é disparado mais de uma vez?

Tags: c#, winforms, eventos

Preciso de um evento, que seja disparado toda vez que o usuário clique no `Form`, tentei usar o evento `Activated` mas o evento é disparado 8 vezes para um mesmo *click*.

Gostaria de entender o porque ele é disparado tantas vezes?

Ao realizar uma breve busca, cheguei em: [Windows Forms Events Lifecycle](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/mamta_m/windows-forms-events-lifecycle/)
, mas ainda não consegui entender o porque ele é disparado 8 vezes para uma mesma ação!

```
    public Menu_Inicial()
    {
        InitializeComponent();            

        this.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.CenterScreen;
        this.Activated += new EventHandler(this.FormGetFocus);

        label3.Text = Sessaosistema.NomeUsuario;
        label5.Text = Sessaosistema.Departamento;
        label4.Text = DateTime.Now.ToLongDateString();
        label1.Text = "Versão: Onee 1.10.17.0 Beta";


        if (ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["490c840431debb47468cbb81db290654"] != "0")
        {
            dat_pais.consulta();  // tabela de paises
                                  // é utilizado em:
                                  // Cadastro de cliente;
                                  // Cadastro de fornecedor;
                                  // Emissão de NF;
                                  // Orçamento;
                                  // Pedido de venda.
        }
        if (ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["b441e9bf13e712e00d99ff2ff5da0af9"] != "0")
        {
            dat_uf.cmbUF(); // tabela de estados
                            // é utilizado em:
                            // Cadastro de cliente;
                            // Cadastro de fornecedor;
                            // Emissão de NF;
                            // Orçamento;
                            // Pedido de venda.
        }
        if (ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["02ea6cbd71130a0e01b7a08403a44eda"] != "0")
        {
            dat_cidade.consulta_cidade(); // tabela de cidades
                                          // é utilizado em:
                                          // Cadastro de cliente;
                                          // Cadastro de fornecedor;
                                          // Emissão de NF;
                                          // Orçamento;
                                          // Pedido de venda.
        }
        if (ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["4a35aa35aaa7467ff2ad41ed6806b591"] != "0")
        {
            dat_ncm.consulta(); // tabela de ncm
                                // é utilizado em:
                                // Cadastro de produto no estoque;
                                // Emissão de NF;
                                // Orçamento;
                                // Pedido de venda.
        }
    }

 private void Menu_Inicial_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Thread.Sleep(timeEspera);

        set_font();
        toolTip();

        XtraTabPag_Visible();

        Implat_Table_Aux();

        loadPrinter.PopulateInstalledPrintersCombo();

        if (Sessaosistema.NomeUsuario != "Master")
        {
            button_opsistema.Enabled = false;
            treeView1.Nodes[6].Remove();
        }

        if (ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["4072c1c3f468878a7d48dd7a4564cb57"] == "0")
        {
            button_comercial.Visible = false;
        }

        if (ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["a82a2df07e8039ee4d5a1f46b3f03416"] == "0")
        {
            button_compras.Visible = false;
        }

        if (ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["6cfb561ab73cea537cdb793c22c1aa6f"] == "0")
        {
            button_certificados.Visible = false;
        }

        if (ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["9046c60fefe66f31f80c61379c92843c"] == "0")
        {
            button_equipamentos.Visible = false;
        }

        if (ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["304dac640eee2dfe443840ba5041b7d2"] == "0")
        {
            button_servicos.Visible = false;
        }

        if (ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["14b1cf9d15b50e3cc5a19020bca18f59"] == "0")
        {
            simpleButton1.Visible = false;
        }

        if (ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["a3cb966624ac67ed7d8e77c0f39ba36f"] == "0")
        {
            simpleButton2.Visible = false;
        }

        if (ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["f3c6734eb815854e1ebb0b05cca8a43e"] == "0")
        {
            simpleButton3.Visible = false;
        }

        if (ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["4c91d222b139eeccd6eb342f512ec180"] == "0")
        {
            button_opsistema.Visible = false;
        }

        if (ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["versao"] != "0")
        {
            string local = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory();
            string stgdestino = local + "\\Documentos Empresa" + "\\" + ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["versao"];

            if (File.Exists(stgdestino + "logo"))
            {
                Image logo = Image.FromFile(stgdestino + "logo");
                pictureBox1.Image = logo;

                label_bemvindo.Visible = false;
            }
        }
    }

  private void FormGetFocus(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
            if (Sessaosistema.Departamento == "Compras")
            {
                loadDiligeInicialCompras();
            }
            else if (Sessaosistema.Departamento == "PCP")
            {
                loadDiligeInicialPcp();
            }
            else if (Sessaosistema.Departamento == "PCP")
            {

            }
            else if (Sessaosistema.Departamento == "Estoque")
            {

            }
            else if (Sessaosistema.Departamento == "Qualidade")
            {

            }
    }
```

Comment: Para podermos te ajudar, [forneça um código Mínimo, Completo e Verificável](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Isso não é o comportamento deste evento, pode estar sendo causado dentro do seu código. Por isso, você deve nos mostrar seu código

Comment: Sim, o código deixaria tudo bem mais claro.

Comment: Adicionei parte do codigo! conforme solicitado! obrigado

Comment: Faltou a implementação do clique aí no código, não?

Comment: é necessário saber se esses métodos `loadDiligeInicialCompras()`, `loadDiligeInicialPcp()` dentre outros nesse estão na mesma classe instanciada, caso esses metodos abram qualquer outra coisa que "roube" o foco da sua tela, ela irá ganhar o foco novamente ao sair do metodo, assim disparando novamente o activated

Comment: outra coisa, pode parecer meio boba, mas pode estar acontecendo, em debug mode, se você clicar na sua tela (mesmo pausado) o evento activated será disparado, pois sua tela ganhou foco, pois o foco estava no VS